# MS access Navigation form search technique

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

Just have a small doubt regarding the ms access Navigation forms.

I have created a navigation form in ms access with 3 tabs say tab1,tab2,tab3 and i have some records which mateches the tab1 to tab2 and tab3.

I want a search criteria so that i can filter the records from tab1 to tab2.

For example i have a customer in tab1 named ISA and i have the same customer name in tab2 If i click on tab1 customer and click search the filter has to display the ISA in the second tab.

This works for forms i can open the form with such filters but i want it to open in the same navigation form of ms access.

Thankyou for all your response.

Comment: You don't mention if you are using subforms on the tabs or if you are just binding controls? I believe you will need to use subform(s) on the other tabs in order to alter the recordsource.

Comment: Using sub forms on the other tabs is not a good choice we just need to use the sub form under the main form or else the parent and child field relation dont work.

Comment: If you are saying "On Tab1 I show 10 records; and Tab2 will show those same 10 records. Now I want to show ONLY 1 record on Tab2 (your 'filter')", that's not how this will work. By design the same recordsource is used on ALL tabs. Yes, if you filter your FORM, only those records will appear on TAB2, 3, etc. Maybe you can create an unbound combobox on Tab1 to show all records, then when you select one, apply the filter to the form?

Comment: The record source is different i have two tables and two different forms but i have only one commmon field where i can relate both the forms with that field. The Thing is i can filter the form in saparate but i cant filter the form which is attached in the navigation form the main thing why i want this is just to have some convinience in viewing the data which i have in a navigation form.

Comment: Now you mention having two forms; original question mentioned one form with multiple tabs, hence my answer. Now with the two forms, is one a subform of the other? Where do the tabs come into play? With two forms you certainly can alter (filter) the recordsource of either form. Just need clarification.  Thanks.